# Is it possible to use Theano with CUDA 6.5 and CuDNN 3.0?

Tags: theano, theano-cuda

I ran a python program with Theano, but it errors with:

```
   ImportError: cuDNN not available: Version is too old. Update to v5, was 3007.
```

So, is it possible to use Theano with CUDA 6.5 and CuDNN 3.0? Currently, I don't have the root privilege to install a newer version of CUDA (because the newer CUDA needs newer driver).

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` theano from git repo, use `git checkout` to grab an older version, then install locally.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment! I'm using this code `https://github.com/cvlab-epfl/LIFT`. It needs the `https://github.com/Theano/Theano/archive/master.zip`. I'm not sure if the older Theano is suitable.